# how to write text in textbox from database in php

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have a form where I am getting values from previous page in $GET. I want to fetch around 3 different values from database and display them in textbox. How will I do it? Following is my code for getting data from database.

```
<?php
require_once('config.php');
$id = $_GET['id'];
$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
if(!$link) {
        die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
}

//Select database
$db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);
if(!$db) {
        die("Unable to select database");
}
$query = "select question,price,sequence from questions where status = 1 and qid =".$id;
//echo $query;
$result=mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
if($num_rows==0) {
 echo '<center><font color="red"><b>No record found!!</b></font></center>';
}
else {
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $row['question'];
echo $row['sequence'];
echo $row['price'];
}
```

?>

Thanks
Pankaj

Comment: *textbox* as in all the values in a `<textarea>` or `<input type="text"` for each value?

Comment: i want to put each value in different textbox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<textarea><?php echo htmlentites($row['question']);?></textarea>
```

or

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo htmlentites($row['question']);?>" />
```

Depending on your fancy.

Comment: but I get values in an array from database. How will I add it to 3 different textboxes. Please check my code which I am using to fetch values from database.

Comment: I'm assuming `$row['question']` is a string. Right now your code only fetches _one_ record, just fetch two more records?

Comment: it is getting 3 values as string $row['question'], $row['sequence'], echo $row['price']